# DB Indexing & Query Optimizations for Logging

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

For any given logging table where the structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `quantity` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Where entries are being inserted every minute, I understand that it is more efficient to leave this table without an index. However, issues come up when I do attempt compare similar tables with `SELECT`

The following query has an average speed of ~3.7s

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT `t1`.`time`,
           `t1`.`quantity` AS `q1`,
           `t1`.`price` AS `p1`,
           `t2`.`quantity` AS `q2`,
           `t2`.`price` AS `p2`
    FROM `example 1` AS `t1`,
         `example 2` AS `t2`
    WHERE `t1`.`time` = `t2`.`time`
    ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 72
) AS dt ORDER BY time ASC;
```

Is there any way to substantially decrease the amount of time this query takes? A similar query,

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `example`
    ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 72
) AS dt ORDER BY time ASC;
```

only takes ~0.008s. With that, I think it would be more efficient but way uglier to simply execute two separate queries and then compare them using PHP.

Comment: If you want to query your 'logging' table heavily, it makes to add an index as well. But why do you need to heavily query a logging table? I would suggest - because, it is not going to be an operation which would directly help the user, take the relevant rows and process them separately (outside mysql)

Comment: The intensity of the queries would depend on the number of users, as of right now it's only a couple hundred a day.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if this seems a little basic but I find that stripping stuff back to basics can clarify my thinking.

An index is a way of organising your data, there is a price to pay when the data is created. Think of storing paper files in failing cabinet. The quickest way to store them is to jam them in wherever they fit but if you need to find one later you will need to check thru every page in the drawer. If instead you want to store them in date order say you will need to take more time when putting them in but it takes less time to find them.

So there's your trade off - the more indexes you have the slower your INSERTS but the quicker your SELECTS with DELETES and UPDATES falling somewhere in the middle.

For a normal user generated/accessed table there will usually be lots more SELECTS than anything else and they will touch a lot more rows so extensive indexing is indicated. For a log table there will be lots more INSERTS so be cautious with indexes.

However, the overhead of an index that sorts records in the order they are created is much less than one that needs to stick new records in the middle so a log table indexed on date time created will not have a huge overhead.

Also, in your case, 1 record per minute is a very low rate so overhead is unlikely to matter; several hundred per second, not unusual in real time plant logging, is another matter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it's one record per minute per table and I'm at around ~200 tables right now so it's close to 200 per minute and it will only go up. It seems like I'll have to duplicate the tables and see if indexing makes a substantial net difference.